# FreeRDP USB Redirection Not Working on Hyper-V?

Tags: redirect, usb, hyper-v, freerdp

I have compiled FreeRDP from the tip of the Master branch on (and for), an ARM v7 processor, (see cmake command line below).

It all seems to build correctly and the basic xfreerdp client works for a full remote desktop.

I cannot however determine how to get the USB redirection working with a remote virtual server running under Microsoft Hyper-V. I have tried many different command line switch options all without any success, (they also don't produce any error messages).

Reading the "USB Redirection" wiki entry it appears that there should also be a kernel module and service as well as the FreeRDP plugin. I haven't been able to locate any further information on these?

I have also provided a typical xfreerdp command line, (see below), that I have been using in my testing. The remote Hyper-V virtual server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine which has been tested and is fully functional with the Microsoft RDP client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

**My CMAKE Command Line:**

> /usr/local/bin/cmake -DVENDOR=CloudTerminal -DTARGET_ARCH=ARM
>   -DMONOLITHIC_BUILD=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWITH_SSE2=OFF -DWITH_NEON=ON -DARM_FP_ABI=hard -DWITH_GSTREAMER_0_10=ON -DWITH_JPEG=ON -DWITH_CUPS=ON -DWITH_PULSE=ON -DWITH_ALSA=ON -DWITH_CHANNELS=ON -DCHANNEL_URBDRC=ON .

**My XFREERDP Command Line:**

> /usr/local/bin/xfreerdp /bpp:24 /f +compression -clipboard -fonts
>   -aero -decorations -window-drag -menu-anims -themes -wallpaper /t:"Test Terminal" /cert-ignore /sec:tls /d:"DOMAIN"
>   /v:"my.server.com" /usb:id,dev:0c45:6128

I've also tried other USB redirection switches such as:

> /usb:id,dev:0c45:6128 /rfx
>
> /dvc:urbdrc,id,dev:0c45:6128
>
> /dvc:urbdrc,id,dev:0c45:6128 /rfx
>
> /usb:id,dev:0c45:6128 /vc:usbrdr

etc...

**My XFREERDP Response:**

> loading channel drdynvc
>
> Unable to find a match for unix timezone: Etc/UTC
>
> Loading Dynamic Virtual Channel urbdrc
>
> VID: 0x0C45 PID: 0x6128
>
> Regist Device: Vid: 0x0C45 Pid: 0x6128 InterfaceClass = 0xFF

Answer (score 2):

I eventually got it working by following the Serial Redirection instructions on this page:

https://github.com/awakecoding/FreeRDP-Manuals/blob/master/User/FreeRDP-User-Manual.markdown

The USB device I was trying to redirect was an FTDI USB-RS232 adaptor.

BTW: This was the only Serial Redirection reference I could find which actually shows a correct example of the command line syntax...

Note: In my case I didn't have to manually map the remote COM port.